# Padding an image with NumPy returns it all black

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I use NumPy to create a new 2D array with 0 on the border and the array of the original image inside. I print the new array, it's what I expect. But when I plot it, it's all black.

I tried for-loop and NumPy, it's useless.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'test.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path,0)

print(img)
height,width = img.shape       # 440 * 455

new_arr = np.zeros((height+2,width+2), dtype = int)

#for i in range(height):
#   for j in range(width):
#      new_arr[i+1][j+1] = img[i][j]

new_arr[1:height+1,1:width+1] = img
print(new_arr)


cv2.imshow('new image',new_arr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The original image is here:

[image: original image]

I expect an image with black border (just 1 pixel), and the inside is the original image to do median filtering, but the actual output is a black image.

Comment: Try with `np.zeros((...), dtype = uint8)`

Comment: @Cris Won't work, wrong namespace

Comment: @FlashThunder: It’s close, and it points at the problem. I posted as a comment and not an answer because I knew the syntax might not be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you are getting black image, as your code should throw an error. You need to set `dtype` value in proper namespace (`np.`) and the value should be `uint8`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'test.png'
img = cv2.imread(path,0)

height,width = img.shape

new_arr = np.zeros((height+2,width+2), dtype = np.uint8)

new_arr[1:height+1,1:width+1] = img
print(new_arr)

cv2.imshow('new image',new_arr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> **Please note** that the image you have given is `png`, not `jpg`. Code tested on that image.

Comment: Signed 32bit integers are supported by OpenCV `Mat` class, and such arrays can be displayed using `cv::imshow`. This can be verified via documentation, and tested with `cv2.imshow('', np.zeros((100,100),dtype=np.int32)); cv2.waitKey()`. That's not to say `int` is an appropriate choice here, nevertheless the first sentence of your post is incorrect.

Comment: True. Edited my answer, +1 for comment, still int32 in that case will not work.